# How to label the nodes of a graph with the numbers in a list?

Tags: graphics, color, labeling, graphs-and-networks

I have an adjacency matrix "am" and I want to color the nodes with four colors.
Here I what do...

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];
G = AdjacencyGraph[am];
colors = ColorData[97] /@ Range[4];
Graph[G, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack", VertexSize -> 1, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexLabelStyle -> 13, 
 EdgeStyle -> Darker@ColorData["Legacy", "IndianRed"], 
 VertexStyle -> 
  Thread[Range[VertexCount[G]] -> 
    colors[[IGKVertexColoring[G, 4][[1]]]]], 
 ImageSize -> {{600, 900}, {600, 900}}]
```

Note that with this approach, the vertex labels are are taken automatically from 1 to to the number equal to the number of nodes.

But I want to label the nodes with different numbers from a list.

Lets say ID is a list of numbers. and the labels should be taken from this list.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
ids = RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], VertexCount[G]];
```

use the option

```
VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[Style[ids[[v]], White], Center]
```

in `Graph[...]`.